# Does a lower bound for models of finite group schemes exist?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring (as beautiful as you like) and set $K:=Frac(R)$. Let $G_K$ be a finite $K$-group scheme, $G_1$ and  $G_2$ two affine and flat models of $G_K$ of finite type, i.e. two affine, flat $R$-group schemes of finite type (but not finite in general) generically isomorphic. Can we find a lower bound for $G_1$ and  $G_2$? That means: can we find an affine, flat $R$-group scheme of finite type $M$ and two model maps $i_1:G_1\to M$ and  $i_2:G_2\to M$ (i.e. $R$-group scheme homomorphisms which are generically isomorphisms)?

An upper bound can always be found (take the schematic closure of the diagonal $\Delta:G\to G\times G$ in $G_1\times G_2$) and if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are commutative even the lower bound can be found if I am not wrong: when $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite one dualizes the construction of the upper bound (as suggested in Proposition 2.2.2 by M. Raynaud. Schémas en groupes de type (p,..., p)) and if they are not finite but $R$ is Henselian then we can work on the finite parts of $G_1$ and $G_2$ in a similar way. But what happens in the general case?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are the special fibers of the upper and lower bounds of $\mu_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $\mu_2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and the trivial group?

Comment: No : note that there is a model map `$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to\mu_2$` so the upper bound is `$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$` and the lower bound is `$\mu_2$`. But neither `$\mu_2\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$` nor `$1$` have model maps to the original groups -- they just don't have the good order.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. Take any $R$. I think in your case the upper and lower bounds are respectively $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_R$ and $\mu_{2,R}$ since there is a morphism $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_R\to \mu_{2,R}$ which is a model map whenever $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_K$ and $\mu_{2,K}$ are isomorphic (so $char(K)=0$) [see for example the paper of Waterhouse and Weisfeiler, One dimensional affine group schemes]. Furthermore the two group schemes you suggest cannot be good candidates since generically they are not isomorphic (they do not even have order two). 

Comment: Thank you Matthieu. No idea for an answer to my question? I have some candidates in mind...but I cannot prove they are the right ones (maybe because tey are not). So for example: let $G_i=Spec(A_i)$ and let $U:=Spec(B)$ be an upper bound, what about $Spec(A_1\times_{B}A_2)$ or  $Spec(A_1\times_{B_K}A_2)$? I don't know if the fibre product of rings base-changes well and it is not even the main problem.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu and Federigo.  Things make more sense to me now (but I'm afraid I don't have an answer to your question).

Comment: Just an edit to my first comment: I prefer to say "AN upper bound is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_R$ instead of THE" because there are a quasi-finite, affine, flat and of finite type (but not finite) group scheme $Q\to Spec(R)$ with $Q_K=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_K$ and $Q_k=Spec(k)$ (here $k$ is the residue field of $R$) and a model map $Q\to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})_R$. In the setting of my question $Q$ is also allowed. Of course in your example it is not the more natural upper bound.